# How to clear out a lookup value from a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, lookup

I have a flow where I sometimes need to clear the value of a lookup field to a User record. I've tried setting it to nothing (just blank in the update record), I've also tried {!$GlobalConstant.False}, a formula that evaluates to null, and {!$GlobalConstant.EmptyString}.

All of these result in the lookup field showing "System".

This is a record-triggered flow on a custom object record where the lookup object is User.

Any suggestions for my flow?

Comment: What is the lookup object?  What kind of flow is it - record triggered, before or after save, etc? Is the trigger on the User object? Please [edit] your post to include these details and also screenshots of the assignment action.

Comment: @DavidCheng Thanks updated

Comment: What happens when you click on that "system" user?  Do you have any other automation on this object?  You should capture a debug log to see if your flow assignment step is running, and if there's any other automation making changes.